# Is there a way to find all files/objects in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket larger than a certain size?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to use the du command but I'm not sure how to filter by file size.
Trying to do this to delete big files that I simply don't need and are costing me money.

Answer (score 2):

With python you can get a list of all blobs in your bucket and loop through that list to get those with a large size:

```py
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

blobs_list = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_or_name='name_of_your_bucket')

large_files = []
for blob in blobs_list:
    if blob.size > 1_000_000:  # size is in bytes
        large_files.append(blob.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

GSutil offers some ways of sortering the objects inside a bucket, but not by file size; you can use a mix of linux/gsutil commands to help you out. For example, this:

> List objects sorted by size descending with human redible sizes:

```
gsutil ls -lh gs://{bucket} | sort -n -k 1
```

Breaking a little the command:

> [gsutil ls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls): List providers, buckets, or objects
>
> -l: Prints long listing (owner, length)
>
> h: When used with -l, prints object sizes in human readable format
>
> In case you need to do it recursively, add `-r`
>
> [Sort command in linux](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-command-linuxunix-examples/)
>
> -n: To sort a file numerically
>
> -k 1: to sort on a certain column. For example, use `-k 2` to sort on the second column

Answer (score 0):

There isn't native command to achieve this. You need to parse all the file (only the metadata, you don't need to download the content) to get their size and act accordingly.

If your bucket contains lot of files, it could take hours. You can try to parallelize and partition the process by prefixes for example.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this thread and none of the solutions worked for me, I had to use stream to get what I wanted and then wrote my own script and put it in a gist in case it helps others.

https://gist.github.com/JonCatmull/fa55298fd55a565f246ab2e93c5c0e4b

My script just logs all the files over a certain size to a file but you could push them into an array and then perform operations on them if you want.

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import yargs from "yargs";
import fs from "fs";
import { hideBin } from "yargs/helpers";
import { getStorage } from "firebase-admin/storage";

const argv = yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
  .option("bucket", {
    alias: "b",
    description: "bucket to copy images to",
    type: "string",
    demandOption: true,
  })
  .option("maxSizeMB", {
    alias: "m",
    description: "Max file size in MB",
    type: "number",
    demandOption: true,
  })
  .parse();

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp({
  storageBucket: argv["bucket"],
});

function log(msg: string, file = "large-files.log") {
  console.log(msg);
  return fs.promises.appendFile(file, `${msg}\n`);
}

const MB = 1024 * 1024;

try {
  const run = async () => {
    const storage = getStorage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket();

    bucket
      .getFilesStream()
      .on("data", (file) => {
        const size = parseInt(file.metadata.size, 10);
        if (size > argv["maxSizeMB"] * MB) {
          log(`${file.name}
URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/${argv["bucket"]}/${file.name}
Size: ${(size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2)}MB
--------------------`);
        }
      })
      .on("error", (e) => {
        console.error(e);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("done");
      });
  };
  run();
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

## How to setup

### Install

Install gcloud
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

Login and set project

```bash
gcloud init
# or just authorize
gcloud auth login
# then set project to the one that contains bucket
gcloud config set project [project-name]
```

Install script dependencies

```bash
npm i ts-node firebase firebase-admin typescript yargs @types/node
```

### Run

Run with ts-node and pass in bucket name and max file size (e.g. 10MB)

```bash
ts-node ./index.ts  -b your-bucket.appspot.com -m 10
```

Logs values to console and also creates a large-files.log file with path, url and size.